# How can I call a class method from Model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model

app/services/mail_service

```
class MailService
 def subscribe
  code
 end 
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_create :user_subscribe
 def user_subscribe
    Services::MailService.new
 end
end
```

It shows error like `uninitialized constant Services`

Comment: Did you try just using MailService.new?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to write Services just write :-

```
MailService.new
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
require 'MailService.rb'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_create :user_subscribe
 def user_subscribe
    MailService.new
 end
end
```